# Does augmentation in keras modify the dataset at each epoch or it is performed only once?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a question regarding the image dataset function `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` and augmentation: If we set a seed in this dataset creation function a provide some augmentations layers in the model (those layers also with a seed specified), will there be new augmented images at each epoch or will it always train on the same set of augmented images.

Example:

```py
# model construction
model_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(96, 96, 3))
add_layers=tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip(mode='horizontal',seed=75398)(model_input) # augmentation
add_layers=tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(factor=0.1,seed=2143)(model_input) # augmentation
add_layers= #some nn layers# # model core
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(add_layers)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
# datasets construction
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(dataset_directory,
                                                          labels=[1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...], label_mode='int',  
                                                          image_size=(96, 96), batch_size=32,
                                                          shuffle=True,
                                                          seed=2342)
dataset_length = [i for i, _ in enumerate(dataset)][-1] + 1
dataset = dataset.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
validation_split = 0.1
train_set = dataset.skip(int(dataset_length * validation_split))
validation_set = dataset.take(int(dataset_length * validation_split))

# training
model.fit(train_set, validation_data=validation_set, epochs=5)
```

In this example will the augmented images be the same during the 5 epochs or will each epoch create a new set of augmented images? If this will use always the same images, how can I increase the number of images I train with with augmentation?

Answer (score 0):

The images are augmented right when the image_dataset_from_directory method is executed. Hence, no, it will not create new images for each epoch. Also, for increasing the number of images with augmentation, try reading this blog:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/image-augmentation-with-keras-preprocessing-layers-and-tf-image/

Comment: I am not sure I understand how the images are augmented when the `image_dataset_from_directory` is executed. This function does not know which augmentations are to be performed as they are defined in the model first layers and the model is not passed to `image_dataset_from_directory`...